# How to set upper and lower bounds to a gene in an individual in DEAP?

Tags: python, nonlinear-optimization, genetic-programming, deap

I am employing genetic algorithm through DEAP package in python.
In this process, I would like to set different upper and lower bounds to each gene in the individual.

I would like to know how can one do that?
For more illustration,
Suppose my individual has two genes then I would like to give the following bounds

[image]

gene1: should be bounded to 0,1
gene2: should be bounded to 2,3

Comment: Do the bounds only apply to the initial population, or to all generations?

Comment: To all the future generations as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the creation of a bounded initial population, see [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47719547).

For enforcing bounds in subsequent generations, see [this DEAP documentation example](https://deap.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorials/basic/part2.html#tool-decoration).

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply. However, i have one query. Rather than using the decorator, if after the generation of an offspring, i manually check for the upper and lower bound of each gene in the offspring and limit it within the bounds then would it come in the way of the algorithm?

Comment: The code: 
`offspring = toolbox.select(pop, len(pop))
        # Clone the selected individuals
        offspring = list(map(toolbox.clone, offspring))
        for child in offspring:
            for i in range(len(child)):
                if child[i] > dic[i][1]:
                    child[i] = random.randint(dic[i][0],dic[i][1])
                elif child[i] < dic[i][0]:
                    child[i] = random.randint(dic[i][0],dic[i][1])` Would this code come in the way of the randomness of the algorithm?